# Shutting down an X amount of identical program instances, in a custom manner

Tags: windows, instance

To give some context, I have about 20 live trading terminals (program instances) running on a laptop. Sometimes, when there are big news scheduled for the day, I like to leave only about 2 instances running, just to see and note what will become of them, under live circumstances (there are still 5+ other terminals running at all times, since they are demos)

So hence, I'm looking for something that would be able to shut down an X number of instances from the right side of the taskbar.

**Solutions I have considered:**

• Having a macro that closes down the terminals, however, it would really be nice to have something that would run in the background. For example a little program that would close X first amount of taskbar items, starting from the right

• Shutting down all instances with a batch or the like, however, I would then have to reopen demos, which would be fine if not for situations where they'd have lots of trades pending, where shutting them down, could end up having unintended consequences

**Thing I have tried:**

Using a program like Unlocker, to attempt shutting down the instances, by selecting the folders within which the terminals are in. This however didn’t work, as the .exes are buried deep within other subfolders, so I can’t just select multiple terminal folders inside of “C:\Program Files (x86)”  and kill the processes

**Notes:**

• All instances are called terminal.exe inside of Task Manager

• Any other types of solutions are much welcome

[image: Terminals, accessed from a remote control software]